# Django Markdownx preview shown only after reloading page

Tags: python, django

I want `django-markdownx` to show maths formulas and equations and therefore integrated '[python-markdown-math](https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math)' with it. Everything works as usual apart from the fact that I need to reload the page to get a preview of the typed mathematical formulas or symbols.

The issue is only occurring when I type mathematical formula not others texts or upload image. Maths related stuffs (like $$..$$) seems to get skipped in preview and is shown only when I reload/refresh the page.

Parts of my code:

```
# settings.py 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'

MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = [
    'mdx_math',
]


MARKDOWNX_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024  # 5 MB


MARKDOWNX_SERVER_CALL_LATENCY = 1000


MARKDOWNX_IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = {
    'size': (500, 500),
    'quality': 90,
    'crop': True,
}

MARKDOWNX_MEDIA_PATH = 'markdownx/'


# models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    content = MarkdownxField()

    @property
    def get_content(self):
        return mark_safe(markdownify(self.content))


# in my template 
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>

{{ form.media }}

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me find the problem which is causing such a behaviour.

**Note**: Reloading and getting correct output works only in Firefox. Chrome just resets the the `textarea`.

Comment: are you sure mathjax is being loaded and used correctly?

Comment: @Jason, No. I am new to django and web development in general. I read stuffs here and there and try to implement them. The CDN is same as mentioned on their documentation.